# How should I manage my memory in cpp with calling a C-style interface?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to manage pointer with smart pointer in my code, however I must call old C-style interface to get pointer, like that:

```
void getPointer(T** pT, int* pSize);
```

Users pass an empty pointer of Pt and return a pointer, I want to manage it with smart pointer in my code like

```
std::shared_ptr<T> ptr;
```

How should I write my code? I have been told that use get() method is not a safe idea.
Another question is, how should I safely copy memory stored in smart pointer to a raw pointer? (or vice)

Comment: Everything depends on who has ownership of what. (The smart "pointers" are more about formalizing rules of ownership than they are about memory management.)

Comment: what does `getPointer` do with the pointer?

Comment: `get()` will not work. You should first obtain the pointer from your C API and then create smart pointer from that. But, if this is really C, check whether the memory is allocated with `new[]`, because if it uses `malloc` you will need  custom deleter.

Comment: We pass  `pT` as `nullptr`, and in C interface, it will `new` a T type pointer. Previously, in our code, we delete the pointer by ourselves. It was very old code style and hard to manage the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a `std::shared_ptr<T>` (or a `std::shared_ptr<T[]>`) from a `T*`. If the `T`(s) weren't allocated with `new`(`[]`), you will need to provide the correct deallocation to the shared pointer.

Assuming that there is a `void returnPointer(T* pT, int size);` in that C interface.

```
struct C_interface_deleter {
    void operator()(T* ptr) { returnPointer(ptr, size); }
    int size;
};

void use_C_interface() {
    T* raw;
    int size;
    getPointer(&raw, &size);
    std::shared_ptr<T> ptr(raw, C_interface_deleter{ size });

    // stuff involving ptr
}
```